# How do I encode Reddit Data using Fast Text (running into Key Error)?

Tags: fasttext

I'm running into a Key Error when I try to convert a column that contains Reddit data into Fast Text vectors. I've cleaned the Reddit text so that each row is a list with the words of the blog (all numbers & punctuation removed). Would appreciate any advice on how to get around this key error!

```
def abstract2vec(a, vecs):
return np.array([vecs[w] for w in a if w not in stop_words.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS]).mean(axis=0)
```

EDIT: Yes, I believe this is because I'm trying to retrieve a word vector for a word that isn't in the mode's vocabulary. Does anyone have advice on how to change the function to address that?

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you, but a fair guess is that you're trying to retrieve the word vector for a word that isn't in the model's vocabulary. FastText itself allows you to generate word vectors for missing words from portions of the word, you could try using the official FastText python API.

Comment: Yes. Please show full code.

Comment: What is `a`? What is the type of `vecs`? (Which Python FastText library are you using?) What is the full verbatim `KeyError` stack shown? (Best to add these details into your question.)